# Standalone page navigation problems in php and browsers back button issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Standalone page navigation problems i mean in a project i have more than 5 pages.
User compulsory to follow the order to navigate the pages(page 1 -> page 2 -> page 3....).
If the user directly hits the the page 3 i am redirecting to 1st page.
i am doing like this In page 1 when user clicks the submit button it self i am added the variable to session (usernamespace-> navpage = 'page 2')

and in page 2 to i am checking

if(usernamespace-> navpage == 'page 2')
   //nothing

else

redirecting to page 1;

I have a problem when i am in 3rd page user clicks the browsers back button it will not redirect to 2nd page because usernamespace-> navpage == 'page 3' in history.

Please suggest me to change the navigation's logic which is not related affected to above browser issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make your session data an array, and set keys according to pages completed:

```
//page1
$_SESSION['pages']=[];
$_SESSION['pages'][1]=true;

//page2
if(!isset($_SESSION['pages'][1])
    //redirect
$_SESSION['pages'][2]=true;
//page3
if(!isset($_SESSION['pages'][2])
    //redirect
$_SESSION['pages'][3]=true;
//etc etc
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response,
After completing the 5 pages we store the 5 pages in array and total pages having more than 5.
In case user directly hits the 3rd page through browser url this time i will go to 3rd page(because session already having) actively i will redirect to 1st page .....

Comment: @user3915009 After completion of the final page, simply unset the session variable: `unset($_SESSION['pages']);`

Comment: I have a problem in that 
I have total 6 pages After completing the 4 pages by chance user  directly hit the page 2 through browser url in this case i redirect to page 1 but an am unable to redirect because in session page 2 also contains.....

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand your question correctly. Could you put an OR in there?

```
if(usernamespace-> navpage == 'page 2' || usernamespace-> navpage == 'page 3' )
//nothing
```

or if that doesn't suit your application you could make another session var that is the previous page... this variable gets the previous value when navpage gets updated..

User clicks submit on page 1 and:

```
usernamespace-> navpage = 'page 2'
usernamespace-> prevpage = 'page 1'
```

Then on page 2 you have...

```
if(usernamespace-> navpage == 'page 2' || usernamespace-> prevpage == 'page 2')
//nothing
```

Then when the user gets to page 3 just make sure the prepage stays at 'page 2' as long as they don't submit.

Comment: Then Steve has the right idea. Having a separate session var (or an array) for each page and ensuring each previous page has been seen before allowing the user to view. And then on the last page 'unset'ting the Session var. :-)

Comment: Thanks for quick response, After completing the 5 pages we store the 5 pages in array and total pages having more than 5. In case user directly hits the 3rd page through browser url this time i will go to 3rd page(because session already having) actively i will redirect to 1st page .....